# twenty-sixteen broken child-theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I’ve moved to the twenty-sixteen theme and used a child-theme to do the editing. I wanted to make the site a little narrower when viewed at full screen, move the header and nav menu about so I’ve added this code to my theme.

```
.site-inner {
 margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1140px;
    position: relative;
}
.site {
 margin-left: 300px;
 margin-right: 300px;
}

.header-image img { 
display: block; margin: 0 auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 910px) {
.main-navigation .primary-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
.main-navigation ul {
    text-align: center;
}
}
```

Thing is, now the responsiveness doesn’t work and is unreadable at phone level. Any help please to tell me what I’ve done wrong and a work around? I think its the margin 300’s.

my site is [www.alienmilkshakes.com](http://www.alienmilkshakes.com)

many thanks for looking

Answer (score 0):

Use media query to ignore margins at lower screen size:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1120px) {
    .site {
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-right: 300px;
    }
 }
```

Value of min-width adjust yourself.